# Getting the element reference and new value on onChange event in vuetifyJS v-switch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I display `v-switch` using a `v-for` loop

```
<tr v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
  <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
  <td>
   <v-switch :input-value="product.currentUserTracking"
             dense
             inset
             @change="trackingStateChanged"
   ></v-switch>
  </td>
 </tr>
```

Whenever the state of any of the `v-switch` changes, I want to know the `id` of the corresponding product and the new value. I tried the following approaches

**1st Approach**

```
@change="trackingStateChanged"

trackingStateChanged(event) {
  console.log(event) //event contains the new value(true/false)
},
```

**2nd Approach**

```
@change="trackingStateChanged(event, product.id)"

trackingStateChanged(event, productId) {
  console.log(event) //event is undefined
  console.log(productId) //productId is available e.g pr345665
},
```

I am not able to get both `product.id` and the `new value` with either approach. Any idea how this can be achieved.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$event` instead of `event` in `@change`. You can get the value using these:

```js
@change="trackingStateChanged($event, product.id)
```

```js
trackingStateChanged(event, productId) {
  console.log(event);
  console.log(productId);
},
```

From [vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers) web site:

> Sometimes we also need to access the original DOM event in an inline
> statement handler. You can pass it into a method using the special
> $event variable.